# Sqlite Android Quick Question

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I wanna pull a random entry in my database that has downloaded value as 0. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE downloaded=0 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```